# Issue with Entity Framework 7 Shadow Property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

This is EF 7 (now Core). I have a shadow property named CreatedBy. EF correctly loads its value from data store, the value of this property remains accessible as long as I use the same DbContext instance but I need to work in detached way, and submit changes later using another DbContext instance.

The problem is that for subsequent DbContexts all shadows properties are NULL, and so far I cannot see anyway to get it loaded. So before get rid of this shadows I need to know if somebody already have come across for a solution for this issue.

If it could help, here is how proceeding with here:

```
var cached = Cache.Get<MyType>();
cached.Default = false; //some updating
var dbContext = new MyContext();
dbContext.Attach( cached );
dbContext.Entry( cached ).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

SaveChanges is submitting NULL value for shadows property.

Comment: Looks like shadow properties force you to get the entity from the database and "repaint the state" with the data from the disconnected client.

Comment: @GertArnold it seems so, AFAIK this feature was created to map and abstract entities from columns such as RowVersion, CreatedBy,CreatedDate, etc. With this behavior imho it makes shadow properties useless.

Comment: I agree with you. When I first heard of it, I wondered: did we ask for this? What's the business value? The statefulness of the feature is the bummer here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the cached object directly to the table/object it belongs to instead of directly to the context.  For example:

```
var existingBlog = new Blog { BlogId = 1, Name = "ADO.NET Blog" }; 

using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    context.Blogs.Attach(existingBlog); 
    context.Entry(existingBlog).State = EntityState.Modified; 
    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

You are doing context.Attach() directly and this will not work.  Go here, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx, for more info.

Comment: Thanks Ben, unfortunately this will not work for EF 7 shadows properties.